# SQLite forces sort on SELECT

Tags: sqlite

I've a very strange problem with sqlite3 - running sqlite3 version 3.20.1 for windows.

The same SELECT query on two different tables generate different results. However the column data type, and data is the same in both. Here are the CREATE and INSERT statements.

```
CREATE TABLE key(key INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE map(key INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, char TEXT);

WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt LIMIT 9999) INSERT INTO key(key) SELECT x FROM cnt WHERE x >=1000 ORDER BY random();
WITH RECURSIVE cnt(x) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM cnt LIMIT 9999) INSERT INTO map(key) SELECT x FROM cnt WHERE x >=1000 ORDER BY random();
```

This should insert the numbers from 1000 to 9999 randomly ordered into both columns. However the SELECT statement on the second table is always sorted. Here is the results

```
sqlite> SELECT key FROM map LIMIT 10;
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1008
1009
sqlite> SELECT key FROM key LIMIT 10;
6165
1856
2457
2343
9095
8005
4958
4781
8334
1863
```

I've even tried the following;

```
sqlite> DELETE FROM map;
sqlite> INSERT INTO map(key) SELECT key FROM key;
sqlite>
sqlite> SELECT key FROM map LIMIT 10;
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1008
1009
```

It's still sorted! Using REPLACE didn't help, too.
I've tried even changing the table schema a bit by adding id column first but didn't success either.

After some experiments I've found that `SELECT *` shows it in the right order but `SELECT key` gives ordered result.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM map LIMIT 10;
8418|
5869|
9753|
2886|
8354|
8244|
4063|
6692|
5440|
3508|
```

Can you explain this? Is it a bug or a feature? How can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.

If you want a query to return rows in a random order, you must use `ORDER BY random()` in the query itself.

(To return rows in the internal order, use `ORDER BY rowid`, but this does not work for [WITHOUT ROWID tables](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).)

---

The index for the UNIQUE constraint uses less storage then the table because it contains only one column.
So as long as you want to read only this column, the query optimizer prefers to read the values directly from the index (as a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx)), because reading less data from disk makes the query faster:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT key FROM map;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE map USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_map_1
```

That the returned rows then happen to be sorted is just a side effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful!

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY ROWID` gives the expected result.

Comment: I got the same problem, but the query result was still to be sorted while I was adding order by rowid, is it SQLiteStudio feature?

Comment: @WLiu You have a different problem. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

> This should insert the numbers from 1000 to 9999 randomly ordered into both columns. However the SELECT statement on the second table is always sorted.

You don't understand SQL.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  That means that the SQL engine can decide how to store the data however it wants.

SQL queries return *unordered* sets.  That means the SQL engine can decide the ordering of the result set -- unless you specify the ordering.

In this case, SQLite is returning the result set based on the unique key in the table -- it is using the index for the query.  (SQLite may actually be deciding that the unique key is the primary key of the table.)

Comment: Thanks. But why `select *` result is different from `select column` if it's to be ordered by the same "primary key" ?
Can you also please add a reference for such behavior?

Comment: @Dawood . . . It would be using the unique index in one case and the data pages in another.  If you want data in a particular order, then use `order by`.